# For groups elements $a$ and $b$, how do you prove that $(a^{-1}ba)^n = a^{-1}b^na$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> For any elements $a$ and $b$ from a group and any integer $n$, prove that $(a^{-1}ba)^n = a^{-1}b^na$.

Suppose $P(n):$ $(a^{-1}ba)^n = a^{-1}b^na$.

$1.$ $n=1$ $(a^{-1}ba)^1 =a^{-1}ba =a^{-1}b^1a$

$2.$ Suppose $P(n)$ is true we want to show $P(n+1)$ is true.

$(a^{-1}ba)^{n+1}=(a^{-1}ba)^{n}(a^{-1}ba)=(a^{-1}b^{n}a)(a^{-1}ba)$

Then using associative and inverse property this reduces to 
$a^{-1}b^{n+1}a$

Thus $P(n+1)$ is true, therefore $P(n)$ is true for every natural number.

I'm not sure how to show it for the negative numbers or could I just use this result to conclude it holds for the negative numbers also.

Comment: Usually you can handle negatives by inducting again, but in the other direction.  Or, you can sometimes prove it for exponent $-1$ and get the rest by some sort of obvious repeated multiplications.

Comment: Replace $n$ by $-n$ and repeat the induction.

Comment: Repeating the induction works, but it's overkill. You can just pull out the $-1$ power and use what you've already proved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the induction:

$$\begin{align}
(a^{-1}ba)^{-n} &= ((a^{-1}ba)^n)^{-1}\\
&=(a^{-1}b^na)^{-1}\\
&=a^{-1}(b^n)^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=a^{-1}b^{-n}a
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi, I know that this is a very late comment on this answer, but I don't understand how you jump from $(a^{-1}b^na)^{-1}$ to $a^{-1}b^{-n}a$. Shouldn't you instead be getting $ab^{-n}a^{-1}$? @G Tony Jacobs

Comment: @Sparklestheunicorn, remember that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. You can see this by multiplying the two inverses together: With $(a^{-1}b^na)(a^{-1}b^{-n}a)$, everything cancels, from the middle outwards.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you prove
(for $n\geq 1$)
$(a^{-1} ba)^n (a^{-1} b^{-n} a)$
is equal to the neutral element of the group,
thus calculating the inverse of $(a^{-1} ba)^n$.

This way, you dont need to do another induction.

Answer (score -1):

Induction is overkill. Just write it down:

$$
(a^{-1}ba)^n = 
\underbrace{(a^{-1}ba)(a^{-1}ba)\dotsb(a^{-1}ba)}_{n \text{ copies}} = 
\underbrace{a^{-1}baa^{-1}ba\dotsb a^{-1}ba}_{n \text{ copies}} = 
a^{-1}\underbrace{bb\dotsb b}_{n \text{ copies}}a = 
a^{-1}b^na
$$

Comment: Induction is a way to not have to use "$\cdots$".

Comment: I disagree: Every time you write $...$, it's hiding an induction.

Comment: Alright, so it should read, "having to formally write out the inductive proof is overkill."

Comment: It's not overkill if you're trying to practice writing formal induction proofs.

Comment: I think it depends on the level of mathematical education whether one can use $\dots$ instead of a (formal) induction.

Comment: Your answer does not work well for negative $n$ (hard to make $-3$ copies). However, this is the case OP explicitly asked about, not the case for positive $n$.